# download a file from google cloud storage with the api

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage

I currently use gsutil cp to download files from my bucket but that requires you to have a bunch of stuff installed.

I just want to download it using a simple API request like:

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/pulltest/pulltest.csv
```

This gives me access denied. How are the auth parameters formatted to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to do what I wanted:

```
from google.cloud.storage.client import Client
from google.cloud.storage.bucket import Bucket
from google.cloud.storage.blob import Blob
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file('key.json')
client = Client(project='project', credentials=credentials)
bucket = Bucket(client=client, name='bucket')
blob = Blob(name='pulltest/pulltest.csv', bucket=bucket)

print blob.exists()
```

Answer (score 2):

If your object can be downloaded by an anonymous user, you can download an object exactly like that.

Doing OAuth by hand is tricky, though. The thing you'll need to present to Google is an access token. The auth header looks like this:

```
# This has gotta be in an HTTPS request. No sending credentials over HTTP, please.
Authorization: Bearer something.abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd
```

Getting an access token requires an OAuth exchange, which is a bit tricky. There's an online playground that will take care of it for you: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

There's also a bunch of documentation on the exact details, although you likely won't want to do it by hand: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Access tokens are only good for a few minutes. They're not meant to be persisted. If you're going to be doing this a lot, you may want to install the gcloud SDK, which has a "[print-access-token](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/auth/application-default/print-access-token)" command that is very useful.

Comment: is there a way to gcloud auth login without using the terminal? i.e through python since i would like to deploy my script using amazon lambda

Comment: Sure. You want to create a service account that represents your app. Deploy your script along with the private key for that service account and use it for auth.